# Tizen Memory buffer into byte array

Tags: pointers, tizen

In Tizen IO there is a function that feed the microphone data into a pointer (memory buffer), **I want to copy the buffer data and return it in `uint8` array** (byte array), below for reference is the buffer definition and the function

```
buffer_size *= 10 * RECORDING_SEC;
buffer = malloc(buffer_size);
audio_in_read(audio_in_h input, void *buffer, unsigned int length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data type 'uint8_t'. Its already defined in stdin.h, you don't even have to include the header.

audio_in_read() function returns the number of bytes read. I am sharing a Sample Code Snippet here:

```
uint8_t byteArray;      
int byteArrayLen, bytes;

bytes = audio_in_read(handle, buffer, len);

byteArray = buffer;
byteArrayLen = bytes;
```

Comment: i don't get it, what is samples in (byteArray = smaples;),  because that is the part that is important to me i want the value of the buffer in a byte array ?

Comment: Just a typing mistake. I named the variable 'buffer' as 'smaples' earlier, that remained on my code. Edited.